# Java scanner restrict integer < 1 & string input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Trying to figure out how to get my program to restrict the input of a integer less then 1 and also restrict input of strings in the scanner. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Import scanner object
import java.io.*; // Import for file and IOException

public class Distance {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int distance;
        int speed, time;
        String filename;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Distance Calculator.");

        // Create a scanner keyboard for user input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Vehicle speed
        System.out.print("Vehicle speed (MPH): ");
        speed = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid #: ");
            speed = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (speed < 1) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a # greater then 1: ");
                keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Time vehicle traveled (HR): ");
        while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            time = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (time < 1) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid time: ");
                speed = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

        time = keyboard.nextInt();

        keyboard.nextLine(); // Consume next line

        // Get filename
        System.out.print("File name for saving: ");
        filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Open file
        String filePath = "C:/Users/Nik/Desktop/";
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filePath + filename);

        outputFile.println("Hour        Distance Traveled");
        outputFile.println("-----------------------------");

        for (int hour = 1; hour <= time; hour++) {
            distance = (speed * hour);
            outputFile.println(hour + "\t\t\t" + (distance + " Mi"));
        }
        outputFile.close();
        System.out.print("Date written to " + filePath + filename);
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: What if speed is equal to 1?

Comment: I updated the code. It's basically a distance calculator that then outputs to a file. I only want to allow numbers that are speed > 1

Comment: What happen if you enter 0?

Comment: I only want to allow input of integers greater then 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe that changing the "whiles" a bit like this might work like you want it to. It takes care of both the input problem when you insert something that's not an integer and the positive integer problem when a non positive integer is inserted. I tested it and I think it worked how it's supposed to. Try it out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int distance;
    int speed, time;
    String filename;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Distance Calculator.");

    // Create a scanner keyboard for user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Vehicle speed
    System.out.print("Vehicle speed (MPH): ");


    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt() || 
            ((speed = keyboard.nextInt()) < 1) ) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid #: ");
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.print("Time vehicle traveled (HR): ");

    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt() || 
            ((time = keyboard.nextInt()) < 1) ) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid #: ");
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    keyboard.nextLine(); // Consume next line

    // Get filename
    System.out.print("File name for saving: ");
    filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    // Open file
    String filePath = "C:/Users/Nik/Desktop/";
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filePath + filename);

    outputFile.println("Hour        Distance Traveled");
    outputFile.println("-----------------------------");

    for (int hour = 1; hour <= time; hour++) {
        distance = (speed * hour);
        outputFile.println(hour + "\t\t\t" + (distance + " Mi"));
    }
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.print("Date written to " + filePath + filename);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the assistance! you response helped spark my end result. I ended up creating a boolean that initialized as false.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
System.out.print("Vehicle speed (MPH): ");
speed = -1;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer greater than 1");
    if (keyboard.hasNextInt() {
        speed = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
} while (speed < 1)
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is coming from the `!` in your while loop, however I think I have managed to clean up the code.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code to see if it works, however I thought I would give it a shot, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My final code:

```
int distance;
        int speed = 0, time;
        String filename;
        boolean validInput = false; // Boolean for validating scanner input

        System.out.println("Welcome to Distance Calculator.");

        // Create a scanner keyboard for user input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Vehicle speed
        System.out.print("Vehicle speed (MPH): ");

        // Method for validating user input
        while (validInput == false) {
            if (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) { // check if keyboard scanner !integer
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid #: "); // prompts user for valid input
                keyboard.nextLine(); // consumes next line
            }
            else {
                speed = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (speed < 1) { // validates if speed > 0
                    System.out.print("Please enter a value greater then 1: "); // prompts user for valid speed
                    keyboard.nextLine(); // consumes next line
                }
                else validInput = true; // if statements are passed then set bool to True and end loop
            }
        }
```